# What’s the ideal overhang for a 26’ LVL beam?

Tags: structural, beam

We just installed 3 LVLs (3) x 1 3/4x 24” x 25’ . Can someone recommend the ideal overhang on the posts for a beam this long? The engineer recommended 8’’ hang on the post on each side, but my contractor only did about 4” on each side. I’m afraid that the overhang might not be enough considering the beam is 25’ long. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You say the engineer "recommended." Can you elaborate on your relationship with the engineer? For example did they draw up plans? Were plans approved for permits?

Comment: Yes, to all of the above. We got structural plans for 8” overhang on each side from the engineer and had the plans approved with the city. We purchased the beam of the recommended size, but my contractor went against plan because he said that if the 8” overhang extends beyond the 4x6 posts it might start to weigh down on the non-load bearing 2x4 studs over time.

Comment: In the USA, the contractor typically does not have the authority to overrule the approved engineer's plans. Whatever is "ideal" is irrelevant in this case. The contractor must build to the stamped engineering plan. No debate to be had. That said, I would highly doubt that 8 inches of overhang in a sizable LVL would weigh down beyond the post at all.

Comment: You might have a problem passing inspection.  The contractor shouldn't be changing the signed and approved plans.

Comment: The only problem that I see here is aesthetics. An inspector *could* call you out on not building to plans, but that seems very unlikely. (And easy to fix after the fact, if needed.) As an aside, I'm suspicious about the contractor explanation, as it seems pretty far-fetched. You think maybe they just cut it wrong?

Comment: Could you elaborate on it being an aesthetic issue? And what you would suggest as the easy fix? I firmly believe my contractor cut too much of the beam and tried to cover up the mistake with his reasoning.

Comment: Are you saying that you have posts supporting the 25' beam and that the beam is cantilevered 4" on the outside of the outside supporting posts?  A picture would help.